# Polymer adding eventListeners

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm using Polymer and I'm rather confused as to when I should use what type of binding. Say for example I have the following code:

```
<body unresolved touch-action="auto">
    <my-app></my-app>
    <polymer-element name="my-app">
        <template>
            <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">
                <core-header-panel drawer id="drawer" mode="seamed">
                    <core-toolbar id="navheader">
                        <span>My Site</span>
                    </core-toolbar>

                    <core-menu selected="0" selectedItem="{{selectedMenu}}">
                        <paper-item icon="home" label="One"></paper-item>
                        <paper-item icon="today" label="Two"></paper-item>
                    </core-menu>
                </core-header-panel>

                <core-header-panel main mode="seamed">

                    <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
                        <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
                        <paper-icon-button id="back" icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
                        <span flex>{{selectedMenu.label}}</span>
                    </core-toolbar>
                    <div class="content">
                        Content goes here!
                    </div>
                </core-header-panel>
            </core-drawer-panel>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer('my-app', function(){

            });
        </script>
    </polymer-element>
</body>
```

In the past, I didn't have this code in a `polymer-element`, but instead just directly in the code. Then I could do stuff like:

```
var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
var back = document.getElementById('back');
var drawerPanel = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');

navicon.addEventListener('click', function(){
    drawerPanel.togglePanel();
});
back.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.history.back();
});
```

However, I have no idea how I should do this inside the `polymer-element`.

Also, I used to use `document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(){ ... });` to be sure that the elements were loaded before initializing them. How do I do this all correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put your old js in the polymer elements script tag. The `ready` function is called when the element is set up.

The second argument of `Polymer()` needs to be an object, not a function.

```
<script>
    Polymer('my-app', {
        ready: function () {
            var navicon = this.$.navicon;
            var back = this.$.back;
            var drawerPanel = this.$.drawerPanel;

            navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
                drawerPanel.togglePanel();
            });
            back.addEventListener('click', function() {
                window.history.back();
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

For more information read the awesome [polymer docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html).

Comment: I was getting my elements using eg `document.querySelector("core-menu")`, using the `this.$.elementId` does work. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, `document` always refers to the root document (outside of all Shadow DOM), even inside the Polymer script code. If you really wanted to you could use `this.shadowRoots['my-app'].querySelector(...)`, but `this.$` is much more idiomatic and DRY.

Answer (score 4):

And to simplify things a little bit more, you could use declarative event mapping:

```
<paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="{{nav}}"></paper-icon-button>
<paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back" on-tap="{{back}}"></paper-icon-button>
```

then define some function properties in your element

```
Polymer('my-app', {
  nav: function() {
    this.$.drawerPanel.togglePanel();
  },
  back: function() {
    window.history.back();
  }
});
```